# Set Android app to debuggable after compiling

Tags: android, debugging

This might be a complete "no-no," but I was wondering if it is at all possible to make an application debuggable after it has been signed and compiled into apk.

I'd like to be able to generate a random key on my server and then use this key to put an application I've published into a debuggable state.

```
//Build a hidden back door to request the randomly generated key on my server
//Input this key into an edittext box of some sort.
//Check this key against the server
//If key validates, put application in debuggable state.
```

I realize the potential security risks in doing this, but I was just wondering if it is at all possible.

Comment: Is there any particular use case you have in mind for this?

Comment: I'd rather not state the actual particular use case, as it could expose a security risk, but I basically want to be able to debug some use cases that I can't replicate in a dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward to generate a debuggable APK from a non-debuggable one if you are willing to re-sign and re-install, but you cannot do so to the already installed instance.

Anything in your actual code which behaves differently based on debuggable/non-debuggable status could also look at something else as Brent suggests, but that's of limited use as most of the debug functionality is built into Android, rather than part of the application code.

You may be able to provide flag-contingent alternatives to debug functionality though.  For example, you can provide something to copy private files out to public storage.  If you really wanted to, you could bake in a server that would provide a shell running as the application UID.  But getting an actual JDWP debugger going may require extreme, android-build-dependent hackery as you'd likely have to provide your own version of a lot of system code.

At the simple end, having your program change its behavior by logging a lot of usually suppressed internal detail would be quite simple.

Do spend some time thinking about the security implications for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the dev site I see access to the flags via a call to `getApplicationInfo().flags;` from a given Context. `flags` is not `final`, so it appears the `getApplicationInfo.flags |= FLAG_DEBUGGABLE;` would allow you to enable debugging at runtime: reference to `ApplicationInfo` doc:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html.

Note, I have not tested this(not by an android environment at the momemnt).

Comment: Probably not effective, as this would only override the result of that expression and would have no impact on other tests of the debuggable state in Android itself and its application startup code.

Comment: Checking the docs it looks like even though the flags class member is not final, the FLAG_DEBUGGABLE member is static and final so it looks like changing this at runtime is a no-go.

Comment: @dell116, FLAG_DEBUGGABLE is static and final because it is a constant. The flags field of applicationInfo is essentially a bitmask, and FLAG_DEBUGGABLE is just the corresponding bit within that mask.

Comment: ie FLAG_DEBUGGABLE just contains the location of the debuggable bit with in the mask not the bit itself.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I am not sure when debug assertions are made. If they are done at startup, then yes, this would have no effect.

Comment: That would be an issue as well, but it's not the real reason why this won't work.  Try doing what you suggest, and you'll see you have not even managed to change the result of the flags as retrieved by a subsequent call to getApplicationInfo().  The ApplicationInfo you retrieve is merely a copy, it's not the actual information on which Android bases its behavior.